# Truncating String killed my hovering tooltip, how to get it back (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, tooltip

I have an angular `ngx-datatable-column` that gives the user a hovering tooltip on mouseover.

```
 <ngx-datatable-column name="Standort" prop="Location" [flexGrow]="1">
    <ng-template let-column="column" let-sort="sortFn" let-sortDir="sortDir" ngx-datatable-header-template>
      <span (click)="sort($event, sortDir, sortFn)"   >Standort</span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template let-value="value" let-row="row" let-rowIndex="rowIndex" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        <span>{{value}}</span>
    </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
```

But the strings were way too long, so I truncated them the following way:

```
<span>{{ (value.length>15)? (value | slice:0:15)+'..':(value) }}</span>
```

By doing so **I unfortunately lost the hovering tooltip.How can I get it back?**
My original idea was to call a function from span like this:

```
<span (mouseover)="myCallHoverFunction(value)"   >{{ (value.length>15)? (value | slice:0:15)+'..':(value) }}</span>
```

here is the function in the typescript file:

```
myCallHoverFunction(nameToDisplay:string):string{
    console.log(nameToDisplay);
    return nameToDisplay;
  }
```

But what exactly should I put inside `myCallHoverFunction()` if I want to see it displayed as hovering tooltip on mouseover event? 
Furthermore I feel that this might not be the best approach, so if anybody knows a better one please do share it with me.

Comment: Instead of truncating why not just apply css ellipsis to the element and both retain the tooltip while also giving the user a cue that the string has more content to it so a tooltip would be expected?

Comment: Great idea but this ellipsis also took away the tooltips. span.b {

    width: 30px; 
  
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  
  }
Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: `overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a solution: simply use 'title' in span. No typescript function needed. Make sure the 'value' is in double curly braces.

```
 <ng-template let-value="value" let-row="row" let-rowIndex="rowIndex"    ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          <span title="{{value}}">{{ (value.length>100)? (value | slice:0:100)+'..':(value) }}</span>
 </ng-template>
```